# How to add tooltip background in google chart

Tags: javascript

To apply the tool-tip background in Google chart,I tried the following CSS code

```
path
{
    fill: #000;
}
```

But this affected the whole google graph..

[image]

How to solve this without using html?

Comment: `fill` will fill entire path. A jsFiddle will help us.

Comment: Thanks for reply..!  Yes.. fill attribute makes the changes in entire graph path background. How to do this in jsFiddle??? Any idea please

Comment: Can you paste your code here? I will make fiddle for you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply for the `div.google-visualization-tooltip` class ?

And I think you have to also enable the isHtml option on the tooltip

```
var chart_options = {
    title: 'London Olympics Medals',
    colors: ['#FFD700', '#C0C0C0', '#8C7853'],
    tooltip: { isHtml: true }
};
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#customizing-html-content

Comment: Thanks.. When applying "isHtml: true", it will change the structure of tooltip box also. I need the same tooltip box with different background color only.

Comment: Is anyway to findout the tooltip path from whole graph?